# Regex Inside a PostgreSQL Extension

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am new to PG extensions and have been learning how to create one.  One of our needs is being able to do some regex operations inside the extension.  I created a simple sample extension to test a pattern that works via PL/pgSQL, but can't make it work via the extension.

I expected it to be true for this pattern and data, but it always returns false.

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(test_regex);
Datum
test_regex() {
  const char* mon_yyyy = "(?i)(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec).*-.*\d{4}";
  text* mon_yyyy_text = cstring_to_text(mon_yyyy);
  char* data = "Jan-2080";
  PG_RETURN_BOOL(
    RE_compile_and_execute(
      mon_yyyy_text,
      data,
      9,
      0,
      (Oid)100,
      0,
      NULL
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Try the most evident fix: `const char* mon_yyyy = "(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec).*-.*[0-9]{4}";`

Comment: This extension is said to be powered by Henry Spencer's regex library, not PCRE.

Comment: The most evident fix did work Wiktor. I was so focused on (?i) and missed the [0-9].  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the string (third argument) should be 8, and the flags (fourth argument) should be `REG_ADVANCED`, otherwise the `(?i)` won't be recognized.

Comment: I tried 8 & REG_ADVANCED, and even removed (?i) as Wiktor suggested without luck.

Comment: And thanks for the REG_ADVANCED, which was needed.  Thanks to both of you.

Comment: If there was anything missing in my answer, let me know so it can be added.

Comment: No, no.  Your suggestion was spot on, and with the note from Wiktor about the changing "\d" to "[0-9]" I was able to get the pattern match to work.  I going to post an updated code block for reference.  Thanks again.

Comment: PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(test_regex); 
Datum
test_regex(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
  const char* char_re = "(?i)(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec).*-.*[0-9]{4}";
  text*       text_re = cstring_to_text(char_re);
  char*       data = "JAN-2080";

  PG_RETURN_BOOL(
    RE_compile_and_execute(
      text_re,
      data,
      sizeof(data),
      /*
       *   REG_ICASE or (?i), or both can be there
       *   \d{4} definitely needed to bechanged to [0-9] 
       */
      REG_ADVANCED|REG_ICASE ,
      (Oid)100,
      0,
      NULL
    )
  );
}